# Automatically enable Public Link on Attachment Upload

Tags: trigger, attachment

I have a Custom Object with Attachments enabled. When a user uploads a file I'd like to automatically enable Public Link Sharing and create the Public Link for the attachment.

I'd also like to automatically add the Public Link to a field in the parent Custom Object.

I'm using the ContentDocumentLink Apex trigger (I am working in the Lightning Experience), and with that I'm able to update data in the parent Custom Object.

I have not found a way to enable Public Link Sharing and Create the Public Link for the attachment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you check my answer if it helps (though not very directly but you may have good indication): https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/181062/how-to-put-large-inline-images-into-rich-text-field-using-content

Comment: Thank you @SantanuBoral – Unfortunately it looks like Content Deliveries are not available in the Lightning Experience. Creating a Public Link for the file appears to be the right approach, I'm just searching for a way to do that via an Apex Trigger on upload so the user doesn't have to do it manually.

Comment: Any Update here?